# Clickable uib-accordion with search filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've encounter a problem when trying to search inside the `uib-accordion` with search filter so that it's status changes to open and at the same time if search is empty user could click the header to open the content. All solutions I've found gives only one option.

Here is what I'm doing as written in solutions - https://plnkr.co/edit/lnWxv7PVR7cfrvrROchb?p=preview

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control"
           ng-model="searchText"
           placeholder="Search"
           type="search"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
 </div>

  <div class="settings-tab">
    <uib-accordion>
      <div ng-repeat="item in vm.data | filter: searchText">
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="searchText.length">
          <uib-accordion-heading>
            <div>
              {{item.name}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
            </div>
          </uib-accordion-heading>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>id</td>
                  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>url</td>
                    <td>{{item.url}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </uib-accordion>
  </div>
```

Problem is that I need both functionality (to search something in accordion and open the filtered ones, also if there is no search let the user click on any drop-down to see what's inside) now it's giving errors in console. Plunkr updated with comments.

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: Updated my post. Please take a look.

Comment: are you trying to filter both headers and the contents with a single `$filter` ?

Comment: Yes, it looks for any match and return those elements i need and this is enough. I just need them to be opened when filter is applied, also keeping the ability to open them manually. Maybe there is a better way, i couldn't say.

Comment: it's a bit tricky, but i think (maybe) a nice way to circumvent a lot of headache would be to user `$filter` the contents inside the tables, but hide a specific `uib-accordion-group` based on some condition, like how many filtered items the group is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've managed to make something i want, for this i've created custom filter that will update open status in returned array. The thing i don't know is the perfomance of this. If anyone have better solutions please post it here.
*Plunkr updated.*

```
function searchFilter() {
  return function(data, q){
       var arr = [];
       angular.forEach(data, function(v){
           if(v.id == q) {
             v.open = true;
             arr.push(v);
           } else if (q == '' || !q) {
             v.open = false;
             arr.push(v);
           }
       })
        // console.log(arr);
       return arr;
  }
}
```